# npm error ENOTEMPTY on babel-loader while npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am trying to install a new dependency and I get this error.
Any hint to fix this please ?

Thanks!

[image]

==> EDIT : I tried to delete that folder and run the npm install emailjs again and it pointed out the same error but for another folder. And it goes on and on and on while deleting the specific folder and trying npm again :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all content in the /babel-loader directory and do it again!
**but make a backup of the directory before deleting..**

Comment: Thanks Jan. I tried but each time I deleted a folder, it was pointing out the same error for another folder :(

Comment: Try to use yarn to install the dependency. Yarn is pretty easy to install and it fixes a lot of issues, so that is worth a shot!

Comment: did not work sadly. I'll put it aside for the moment. If someone has another idea for updating this thread, I'll take it. Thanks a lot Jan

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out a solution to this.
I started a new project from scratch and copied all documents.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be an answer, you can post this as a comments to other answer